# Node.js: Map function doesn't work on query from PostgreSQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, routes

#### I'm creating my first app using Node.js and PostgreSQL.

This app connect's to db and return record to browser in JSON format, its work perfectly till i try to use map function to formating properties. 
When i use map it return an error: 
`TypeError: rows.map is not a function` 
This is my code.

```
 app.get('/car/:id', (req, res) => {

    const car_id = req.params.id;
    const queryString = `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_id= ${car_id}`;

    client.query(queryString, (err, rows, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            res.end();
        } else {
                const car = rows.map((row) => {
                return {"Car_ID": row.car_id}
            });

            res.json(car);
            console.log(rows.rows);
        }
    });
```

Comment: What is `rows`? A string? An object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `result.rows` not just `rows`

According to this - https://node-postgres.com/api/result

```
app.get('/car/:id', (req, res) => {

    const car_id = req.params.id;
    const queryString = `SELECT * FROM cars WHERE car_id= ${car_id}`;

    client.query(queryString, (err, result, fields) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err.stack);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            res.end();
        } else {
                const car = result.rows.map((row) => {
                return {"Car_ID": row.car_id}
            });

            res.json(car);
            console.log(result.rows);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dorian)